# Capture output via subprocess w/o using communicate

Tags: python, subprocess, ipc

I am calling an external program within Python script using subprocess. The external program produces a lot of output. I need to capture the output of this program. The current code is something like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
process.stdin.write('gams "indus89.gms"\r\n')
while process.poll() != None:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    print line
```

The error I am getting with this code is

> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

If I use the following code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
process.stdin.write('gams "indus89.gms"\r\n')
o, e = process.communicate()
print o
```

then the output of the program is not captured.

How should I alter my code so that I can capture the output of the third party program while it runs?

Comment: why do you use `cmd.exe` and `shell=False`, why not `'gams "indus89.gms"'` with `shell=True`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Popen is overkill.

Try:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('gams "indus89.gms"\r\n', shell=True)
```

Hopefully that will work in your environment.

Comment: I tried that but still I couldn't capture the output that I need to capture.

Comment: Sorry, I was running the old code. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for your help..