# How to not have console output printed in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, console

I have a C++ code (written by someone else) which I want to compile and run from a Python Jupyter notebook. However, I don't want the output of the C++ code to be printed in the notebook. Before this was the default behaviour but when I try it on newer versions of jupyter I get all of the output, including that from the console, which clutters things up a lot. How do I get back the old/desired behaviour (other than using older versions)?

Minimal working example:

```
// program.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "I don't wanna see this in Jupyter" << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Code in Jupyter:

```
import os

def run_program():

    print("Compiling program (I wanna see this)...")
    os.system("g++ program.cpp -o program")
    
    print("Running program (I wanna see this)...")
    os.system("./program")
    
    print("Done (I wanna see this)")
    
run_program()
```

Bonus question: how do I silently capture the output of the C++ code so that I can monitor progress without it being printed in the notebook?

Not sure which packages are relevant here. The new installation where things don't work as expected:

```
ipykernel==6.4.2
ipython==7.28.0
jupyter-client==7.0.6
jupyter-core==4.8.1
```

The old installation which works as desired:

```
ipykernel==5.1.2
ipython==7.8.0
jupyter-client==5.3.3
jupyter-core==4.5.0
```

Comment: If you want to run a program and ***redirect*** its standard output to a file, what do you do? Did you try doing the exact same thing, here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture output via subprocess w/o using communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710611/capture-output-via-subprocess-w-o-using-communicate)

Comment: Unrelated: you probably want to compile with optimizations (`-O2`)

Comment: You can try `os.system("./program > output.txt")`

Comment: Redirecting to a file has gotten rid of the output, but it's still not as good as it is with older jupyter versions. Now all of the output is gone. Before, the output of python print went into the notebook and the output of C++ went into the terminal which launched the notebook. That way I could monitor the progress without it cluttering the notebook.

@Botje the real code is compiled with optimization, this is just an example.

Comment: @Botje The answer you linked didn't help, unfortunately. I'm getting the output only after the C++ code finishes. I'd like to have it in real time to monitor progress